# Combine two dataframe to send a automated message

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have two dataframe df1 and df2.I want to combine these two df and send it as a message.

```
 df1 =    Login     Sort                df2 =    Login         Over
          wadd       21                              cashe        5
          khadka     10                              bryan        13   
          Jopal      4                               deshm        9
```

The expected output look like

```
Login    Sort    Login    Over
wadd       21    cashe     5
khadka     10    bryan     13   
Jopal       4    deshm      9
```

I did two for loops to loop through the rows.I works but not as expected.If i use a break keyword it break after first loop and if i do not use a  break keywork if loop 9 times(like 3 for each row).How can i make this work the way i intended.Any help is appreciated. My for loop looks like below

```
body += "\n Login | Defects | Login | Defects  \n --- | --- \n" # this is title
for r in df1.index:
    for j in df2.index:
       
        body +=(
        
            (df1['Login'][r]  + '|' +  df1['Sort'][r] + '|' + df2['Login'][j] + '|' + df2['Over'][j])
            + "\n" 
            )
         break

requests.post(json = {'content':body})
```

Comment: Use `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`.

Comment: I tried that.pd.concat will give NAN

Comment: Why will it give `NaN`? Can you show your exact commands once?

Comment: Ok, it did not give NAN.My bad, but it gives a type error:TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. This if my for loop.... for r in df.index:
        body += (
                 (df['User'][r]  + '|' +  df['Sort Shortage'][r] + '|' + df['User'][r] + '|' + df['Total Defects'][r])
              + "\n" 


        )